# Select2 delete tag with backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-tokeninput

I couldn't find any documentation on deleting tags with the delete or backspace key like you can with jquery tokeninput: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Can you do that with select2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a complete answer, you will need to provide the javascript where you are binding the select2 plugin.

However, Select2 does allow you to delete options with the backspace (like the demo you provided) as long as you use `tags` to fill the dropdown or if you set the option `multiple` to true, like this:

```
Tags<br />
<input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" style="width: 400px;" />
<br /><br />
Multiple<br />
<input type="text" name="multiple" id="multiple" style="width: 400px;" />

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#tags').select2({
            tags:["red", "green", "blue"]
        });

        $('#multiple').select2({
            data:[
                {id: "red", text: "red"},
                {id: "green", text: "green"},
                {id: "blue", text: "blue"},
                {id: "black", text: "black"}
            ],
            multiple: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3fsvwype/).

Comment: Actually I cannot delete tags with backspace even in your jsfiddle demo.

Comment: That is awkward. If you select, for example "red", and press the backspace key twice, the tag doesn't get removed?

Comment: Just tried it in firefox and it works fine. Any reason why it does not work in chrome?

Comment: I have tested with chrome and works as expected. Maybe you have some extension that is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Just tested on a fresh chrome install on a friend's computer and it works fine.

Comment: In case if anyone gets here scratching their heads, https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3354#issuecomment-132389291
You might be looking for this.